# pyaes (a bytes-like object is required, not 'str')

Tags: python, key

I'm using python version 3.9 and I'm studying AES encryption using the Pyaes module, I'm having a problem with the 16-byte key, when I start the program an error says "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' ". I'm following the github examples and there is no change from string to byte.

[error print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRld3.png)

Comment: This should work fine in python 2. For python3, you need to check the type() of variable causing issue and encode that as bytes are required instead of string

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace
`key = ("1234567891234567")`
with
`key = ("1234567891234567").encode()`

This converts the variable key from string to bytes.